# How to "package" a theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to package a theme in WP? When I say theme, I mean all the HTML, CSS, JS, custom post types, etc.

I see these things often on sites like ThemeForest where they have a WP theme for sale. I'd like to do the same for a design of mine that has already been converted into HTML/CSS/etc.

I'm just not familiar with the terminologies, so I'm not sure what to look up.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you currently have a static website with HTML/CSS files and want to package that as a WordPress theme?

Comment: Yes. I plan to buy several ThemeForest themes, but I want to redo the HTML/CSS/JS. And once I'm done with that, I want to integrate into WP. So, I really need some sort of process in place for this.

Answer (score 1):

**For `HTML, CSS, JS`:**

The theme files (actually PHP, CSS and JS) are found in your theme folder. Each PHP file there has its own role based on the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). `CSS` and `JS` files are also present in the theme folder and are called using [`wp_register_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) for `CSS` and [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for `JS`.

**For `custom post types`:**

The WordPress theme folder contains a file called `functions.php` in which you can define your own functions used for that theme. You can add a [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function to that file to define your own custom post types. `register_post_type` should be hooked to `init`. Example taken from the WordPress Codex:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Books' );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

If you add the above example to your `functions.php` file, you will get a new post type called `Books`.

**Custom Variables:**

If you want to save site-wide variables, the [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) allows you to [add](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option), [update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option), [retrieve](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) and [delete](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_option) those variables. Mixed with [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), you can create pages in the Dshboard where users can manage these variables.

**Other things:**

Similarly, you can add your [custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) and [widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) to that file and also add other [hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to modify WordPress Behaviour to suit your needs.

Comment: How about custom "global variables?" Say I needed the user to enter a company name, which will be used throughout the site. How can that be set up in such a way that the user can enter the data. I don't think it's a custom post type, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if `Options API` is what I need. Is there a user interface for this? How will a user enter their company name? I think I need a simple form for the user to enter such data.

Comment: The `Options API` on its own will only allow you to manipulate the data. You can create a custom page using `add_menu_page` and make your own form there. The `Settings API` may help you too.

Comment: Assuming "the user" is the admin of the website then the best way would be adding a custom field to the WordPress dashboard settings.

Answer (score 0):

File structure is going to be variable, correlating to the scope of the project, but there are some industry best practices that you can follow to package your WordPress theme for deployment.

Envato provides extensive documentation on their submission guidelines and addresses formatting standards in a pretty comprehensive manner.  Found here: http://support.envato.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/352/0/general-file-preparation-guidelines

Jeffrey Way, of Themeforest, also provides a step-by-step video screencast walkthrough of the file preparation and submission process for Themeforest templates that should serve as a great reference. Found here: http://blog.themeforest.net/site-news/how-to-submit-a-template-to-themeforest-screencast/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not submitting to ThemeForest. I'm just wondering how to package things.

Comment: The aforementioned information should still help you then.  Envato and Themeforest have some pretty high standards when it comes to entering their marketplace.  Reviewing their file structure should serve as a great example of how to package a WordPress theme.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a WordPress boilerplate I use to convert existing CSS into a WordPress theme...

http://cferdinandi.github.com/kraken-for-wordpress/

Comment: thanks for this resource. I'm new to WP theming. My preference in breaking apart HTML files is to make sure that each file has all its opening and corresponding closing tags withing the same file. For example, `header.php` has the opening `<html>` tag, but the corresponding `</html>` tag is in the `footer.php`. I think this tends to get messy. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie That's how WordPress themes work. Usually everything up to the menu is in the `header.php` (so also the opening body tag) and in `footer.php` you can find the footer, closing tags for body & html

Comment: @user2019515 Has it right. The whole point of a templated CMS like WordPress is so that you only have to write often used content once. With static HTML, you would, for example, need to rewrite your header and nav on each page. With WordPress, you write it once and it gets added everywhere.

Comment: As I read some of your reponses to other comment here, I think your best bet may be to download some free themes from WordPress.org and deconstruct them to see how others structure their themes. Sometimes taking stuff apart and putting it back together is the best way to learn.

Comment: Personally I thought it was very hard to deconstruct/understand the default WordPress theme, so that might not be the best idea. You could try to deconstruct some other themes though. Also, read my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239198/how-to-package-a-theme/15277811#15277811

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your existing HTML/CSS website to a WordPress theme you'll need to do quite a few things:

**1.** Rename your stylesheet to style.css and include a bit of metadata about your theme:

```
Theme Name: Twenty Ten
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: The 2010 default theme for WordPress.
Author: wordpressdotorg
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Version: 1.0
Tags: black, blue, white, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-header, custom-background, threaded-comments, sticky-post, translation-ready, microformats, rtl-language-support, editor-style, custom-menu (optional)

License:
License URI:

General comments (optional).
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet

You also will need to include the WordPress CSS Core, which you can find here: http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes

**2.** Create an index.php file which will be used as "last resort", if no more specific page is found for the current page then this template will be used. More about the different templates you can find here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

If you want a different style for your single pages you'll have to create a file `single.php` that file will be used for those pages. For the page with the blog posts, you'll use `home.php`,... See the link above for more file names.

**3.** Rather than placing the content directly in the files, which we obviously don't want when using WordPress you'll have to use "The Loop". You can read more about that here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Basically, it is an iteration that will loop over all the different posts of the page (category pages and blog home pages will have more posts than a single page).

The following code helped me a lot in understanding "The Loop":

```
<?php // any code included here occurs before the WordPress loop and is always displayed?    >

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php // if there are posts to display, process any code included here only once ?>
    <?php // display any code output from this region above the entire set of posts ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php // loop through posts and process each according to the code specified here     ?>
        <?php // process any code included in this region before the content of each post     ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?> <?php // this function displays the content of each post ?    >

        <?php // process any code included in this region after the content of each post ?    >

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php // stop the post loop and process any code included here only once ?>
    <?php // any code output will be displayed below the entire set of posts ?>
    
<?php else : ?>

    <?php // if there are no posts to display, process any code that is included here ?>
    <?php // the output of any code included here will be displayed instead of posts ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php // any code included here occurs after the WordPress loop and is always displayed ?>
```

Source: http://perishablepress.com/easily-adaptable-wordpress-loop-templates/

WordPress theming is really hard to explain in just a single post, so I hope I helped you out to get you started, obviously, you'll still have to read a lot about it but that's perfectly normal, I look up functions in WordPress function reference every day... so one last link:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/

Good luck!