# Frontend \ Backend Interaction in Themes

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to migrate a simple html theme in Wordpress.

While moving the theme itself wasn't difficult at all, i am now at the point where i have my theme working in Wordpress but, since all the content is simple html, there is no possibility of changing\customizing it from the backend.

Does anyone among you know where i could find a detailed in-depth guide about the subject?
The wordpress codex seems a bit lackluster on the matter ( take http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Options as an example).

It doesn't necessarily have to be a free resource, i could fork out some money if you think the guide\book\whatever it's worth it :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the [Settings API](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-settings-api-part-1-create-a-theme-options-page/) lookup I would suggest you to look for [Redux Options for Admin Panel](https://github.com/ghost1227/Redux-Framework)

This I suggested because, a new theme developer can integrate all he needs in his/her CMS in an unified Admin Options panel with this. Even seasoned developers use this [NHP Options](http://leemason.github.io) (later adopted into Redux Options). These Admin Panel addon is made with the support of [Wordpress Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API%E2%80%8E), so lots of headaches gone!

You might want to get this plugin for you are a beginner. http://codecanyon.net/item/ether-content-builder-wordpress-plugin/1690784
With this Ether Builder you can create really rich content within your posts. Its a commercial plugin and is suitable for non-coders who are at beginner stage but in a hurry to size up his WP site fast. But for a developer I'd suggest thorough learning of the WP codex and tutorials present at the www.nettuts.com and other great sites around the interweb.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a page with theme options I recommend taking a look here: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-settings-api-part-1-create-a-theme-options-page/

It's a good tutorial, but maybe a bit too much for beginners

Comment: The redux options or NHP options is a readymade approach for the beginners instead of diving into Settings API. Even seasoned Theme developers adopting this. I have mentioned this in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you well you currently have a HTML website and would like to convert this to a working WordPress theme, correct?

Please see my answer here: [How to "package" a theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239198/how-to-package-a-theme/15277811#15277811)

Comment: No this was not the question, he asked how he could add an admin panel for his theme (for changing colors etc.)

Comment: He's saying he doesn't have an admin panel yet and currently only has static HTML webpages. Meaning he should first convert his theme in a WordPress t heme before he can add theme options.

Comment: Read the 2nd sentence please : `While moving the theme itself wasn't difficult at all`

Comment: Read the first setnence: `I'm trying to migrate a simple html theme` and `since all the content is simple html, there is no possibility of changing\customizing it from the backend`

Comment: he is not referring to the posts, menus etc., but to the e.g. customization of the logo and the like. He wants to build an admin panel for his theme, have a look at the other answers here, they understood this the very same way.

Comment: We'll see when he answers. I'm leaving this here until we hear from him. Otherwise I'll delete it.

Comment: Damn, i'm truly sorry, i didn't explain myself clear enough, but i actually needed both things! So, thanks to both of you guys, and also thanks to Lenin and Janw too. Now i've got enough stuff to look at to keep me busy for a while :p

Comment: Just edited my post to give you more insight and guideline on your next moves towards learning the Wordpress Theming. @arktoga